Inno Setup 6 High-DPI issue in Select Setup Language Dialog
I updated from Inno Setup 5.6.1 to Inno Setup 6.2.2.
In the new version, my app icon looks very small in Select Setup Language dialog. Please see the screenshot:

Left is Inno Setup 5.6.1, right is Inno Setup 6.2.2.
My app uses a custom ico file. The screenshot was shot in 150% scaling. Other Inno Setup 6 forms look great. I only encountered the high-DPI problem in Select Setup Language dialog.
How to fix the problem?

It seems the problem occurs even with the default icon: 100%: https://i.sstatic.net/ua7aF.png – 150%: https://i.sstatic.net/SkhE6.png – so it looks like a bug in Inno Setup. You should report it to Inno Setup team. We can hardly help you here.

At 150% DPI the default font (Tahoma) becomes 150% in scale horizontally and 146% vertically. This makes the image size 48x47 at 150% DPI, just too small to fit the next available icon wich is 48x48. I suppose I should make the unscaled image 33x33 instead of 32x32. This way it will take the (unscaled) 32x32 icon at 100% and 48x48 at 150%.
